# Word to describe things used in a board game

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing about a board game earlier and I initially mistranslated the Spanish word *material*, which in this refers to everything needed to play the game (cards, the board, the counters, the die...) for the English word *material*, before I realized that in this context they do not mean the same.

What would be the most appropriate English word for this use?

I'm thinking *equipment* or maybe *attire*, but I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Example phrase:

> This board game is very old, I hope all of its ______ is/are still in the box.

Comment: Definitely not _attire_, which is what you wear.

Comment: I've always heard "pieces".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Amongst other suggestions, you could also use the word ***components***:

> **component**
>
> A physical item included in the game. E.g. the box itself, the board, the cards, the tokens, zipper-lock bags, inserts, rule books, etc. See also *equipment*.
>
> (From Wikipedia: [A glossary of terms used in board games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_board_games))

> This board game is very old, I hope all of its *components* are still in the box.

Your suggestion, i.e., ***equipment***, could also be used:

> **equipment**
>
> Refers to physical components required to play a game, e.g. pieces, gameboard, dice.
>
> (From Wikipedia: [A glossary of terms used in board games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_board_games#equipment))

> This board game is very old, I hope all of its *equipment* is still in the box.

From [mykindofmeeple.com](https://mykindofmeeple.com/board-game-pieces-names-examples-uses/):

> What are the pieces in a board game called?
>
> Collectively all the pieces in a board game are called **components**, or less commonly, **equipment**. Common pieces include chits, tiles, counters, chips, pawns, standees and miniatures. Individual pieces usually have names specific to each game.

From [martinsplastics.net](http://martinsplastics.net/en/board-game-manufacturers/):

> What are game boards made of?
>
> Although board games from various parts of the world are different in form and content, **components** such as **board, miniatures, cards, and dice** have similar materials: die-cut cardboard, paper, and plastic.

See also: [List of tabletop *game **components***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tabletop_game_components)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer, particularly from the point of view of game manufacturers and their marketing organizations. For example, the term *components* shows up when enumerating (on the outside of the package or in online advertising) the individual components included inside some particular boxed game that one might purchase. That said, you will often hear these called simply *game pieces* or *game parts* in common, non-technical use.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought of "pieces"  as well (also suggested by Evorlor), but a "board" isn't a "piece". Part, maybe. But not a piece. Pieces generally have a different meaning (the stuff that you move across a board). There's another word, "contents", suggested by Accumulation that could also work. So the "components" or "contents" of a board game would include a "board" as well.

Answer (score 46):

[Pieces](https://www.lexico.com/definition/piece#:%7E:text=A%20figure%20or%20token%20used%20to%20make%20moves%20in%20a%20board%20game.). In the context of board games, "pieces" is the common word.

> This board game is very old, I hope all of its *pieces* are still in the box.

Comment: "Pieces" is often understood to refer to objects placed on the game board to represent in-universe objects. For instance, "pieces" in chess refers to objects that represent military units (and is often taken to exclude pawns). In Monopoly, "pieces" would refer to the objects that represent the players, and possibly the objects that represent houses and hotels, but not cards or dice, or the board itself.

Comment: I think "pieces" is a little bit better than "parts", but I would have understood "parts" as well.

Comment: A "board" (which is required to play a board game) is not a "piece". Pieces are generally bits and bobs such as pawns, tokens, etc. OP needs a word that includes the board as well. Suggestions like "parts", "components", "contents", etc. are good candidates. Pieces, IMO, covers only a part of what OP requires.

Comment: Pragmatically, if I say "All of the pieces are still in the box" and you go to play the game and find the board is missing, you'd be annoyed at my pedantic twittery for not mentioning the board was missing. Technically, I'd be correct, but I'd still be a pedantic twit.

Comment: In normal informal verbal use, I would expect "pieces", "parts" and "bits" to be pretty much interchangeable. The manufacturer probably calls it "equipment" in their docs (and their intellectual property filings) but that wouldn't be common informally. Most commonly I'd expect to say, and hear, "I hope it's all still there" or "I hope nothing's missing".

Comment: @barbecue you're right, but once unpacked the board, cards and dice (continuing the Monopoly example Accumulation raised) wouldn't count as pieces in most people's understanding

Comment: @ChrisH In "most" peoples' understanding? [citation needed]

Answer (score 14):

When the game is sold, the stuff inside is referred to as "contents" (e.g. "Contents: 1 board game, 6 player pieces, 30 cards"). The word "contents" refers to what *is* in the box, not what *should* be in the box, and may be less later on if pieces have been lost, so you can say "original contents" to refer back to what the contents were when it was sold: "I hope all of its original contents are still in the box." You can also say "I hope all of the original game is still in the box." or "I hope all of the complete game is still in the box." (the word "all" isn't necessary for the last example).

Your original translation of "material" isn't terrible, and does correctly describe the stuff referred to, albeit in a manner that some people might find unclear.

Answer (score 12):

> This board game is very old, and I hope that all of its parts are
> still in the box.

This word choice emphasizes that its things that come with the game.  However, it might include parts that are not needed to play the game.

Answer (score 7):

You can try ***paraphernalia***

Defined by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/paraphernalia) as:

> all the objects needed for or connected with a particular activity

Used, for example, in this paper:

> [NEW TABLE GAMES AND
> GAME VARIATIONS IN
> NEVADA
> By Glenn Light, K](https://www.lewisroca.com/assets/htmldocuments/LightRutSing_CL_Fall09%20(2).pdf)
> … the new game paraphernalia samples, such as dice or cards

Comment: If you're a collector looking to buy, sure. But I don't think anyone would say "Put the paraphernalia back in the box."

Comment: "Paraphernalia" suggests something required for gaming that isn't a specific component of that game. A chess clock or poker chips may be thought of as paraphernalia, but Scrabble tiles or Monopoly money probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Meeples**

Meeple is defined at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/meeple):

> A small figure used as a playing piece in certain board games, having a stylized human form.

You might use it as:

> The board game is very old. I hope all the meeples are still in the box.

It’s not *quite* what you’re looking for (it only covers humanoid playing pieces, not cards and dice), but it’s a relatively new word, specific to board games and it might come in handy for the future. It’s also [growing in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Meeple&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).

Answer (score 1):

You could say **set**.

> This board game is very old, I hope the whole **set** is still in the box.

For example, we say **chess set**.

Answer (score 0):

The Spanish *material* in this context means just "stuff". If you can get away with simply using the word *stuff*, I guess it's perfectly correct.

> This board game is very old, I hope all of its stuff is still in the box.